# Issue while changing path

Tags: python

When I use pysftp module I have an issue.

`sftp.cd()` always goes to default home directory.

Why doesn't it go to any other directory and it also appends path with `\n`.

Comment: Could you please show us your effort?

Comment: doc http://pysftp.readthedocs.org/en/release_0.2.8/cookbook.html#pysftp-connection-cd